# Mysql query: combine two queries

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery

Below is an over-simplified version of table I'm using:

```
fruits
+-------+---------+ 
| id    | type    | 
+-------+---------+ 
| 1     | apple   | 
| 2     | orange  | 
| 3     | banana  | 
| 4     | apple   | 
| 5     | apple   | 
| 6     | apple   | 
| 7     | orange  | 
| 8     | apple   | 
| 9     | apple   | 
| 10    | banana  | 
+-------+---------+
```

Following are the two queries of interest:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE type='apple' LIMIT 2;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM fruits WHERE type='apple'; // output 6
```

I want to combine these two queries so that the results looks like this:

```
+-------+---------+---------+  
| id    | type    | total   |
+-------+---------+---------+  
| 1     | apple   | 6       |
| 4     | apple   | 6       | 
+-------+---------+---------+
```

The output has to be limited to 2 records but it should also contain the total number of records of the type apple.

How can this be done with 1 query?

Comment: what's the purpose of such a query?

Comment: This is a trimmed down version of a table I'm using which will have more than a million records, and it's missing 5 other columns. I put this table for simplicity's sake. Right now I'm using 2 queries but wondered how this can be achieved with 1 query (for learning purpose)

Comment: Looks like you oversimplified it and it may mislead ones who will try to answer. Personally I prefer sensible questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM fruits WHERE type='apple') AS Total 
FROM fruits WHERE type='apple' LIMIT 2;
```

Depending on how MySQL interprets it, it may cache the inner query so that it doesn't have to reevaluate it for every record.

Another way to do it is with a nested query and a join (this would be useful it you need more than one fruit type, for example):

```
SELECT fruits.*, counts.total
FROM fruits 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS total FROM fruits GROUP BY type) counts ON (fruits.type = counts.type)
WHERE fruits.type='apple'
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Hey @Lost, aren't your current 2 queries way simpler than this monster? ;)

Comment: @col: Well maybe. But I was curious to learn to do this with 1 query. And yes, though it may not look pretty, I prefer to use 1 query instead of 2.

Comment: @Lost and you'll be wrong. There is not a single benefit in doing it with one.

Comment: @col: hah, this query is a cake walk... take a look at one of these beasts I recently wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938427/converting-delimited-string-to-multiple-values-in-mysql/2938522#2938522 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776632/how-to-return-result-set-based-on-other-rows/2777221#2777221

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` for that.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM fruits WHERE type='apple' LIMIT 2;
```

will return the IDs of your apples, and remember how much it would have returned without the LIMIT clause

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

will return how many apples would have been found, without the limit statement.

Comment: You should put the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in conditional-comments though, to allow graceful failing on SQL-servers that don't support it.